# Importance of teaching as a PhD student to go into academia

Tags: graduate-school, teaching

How important is teaching as a graduate student if I want to then pursue a career in academia. A top program I have been admitted to does not require teaching and I will be fully funded by being a graduate research assistant. Will it hurt my prospects of getting a tenure-track position if I have little to no teaching experience?

I am aware that to get a tenure-track position at a top program, a postdoc is almost always necessary.

--edit-- To address some of the points below, this is for graduate school in the US, with the desire to stay in the US if I were to pursue a tenure-track position.

Comment: Many departments, including mine, pay attention to applicants' teaching strength, both for postdoc positions and for tenure-track positions. I'd advise you to get some teaching experience as a graduate student, even if you're fully funded without having to teach.

Comment: Which countries are you interested in? Please indicate. (Note that many universities do absolutely not care if you are able to teaxh, but claim the opposite.)

Comment: A lot depends on the discipline.  For example, in mathematics, teaching experience is far more important than in some other science disciplines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is the US or in a place with similar traditions, then nearly all academics teach. Some more than others and some only at advanced levels, but generally, we teach.

If you are good enough to be hired primarily as a researcher at an R1 university in the US then the hiring decision won't hinge much on your background as a teacher, but for most other academic jobs it will be a consideration, perhaps an important one.

So, it is a good thing to get some experience with it, though it is time consuming the first few times. Post doc positions don't necessarily provide any teaching experience, though some do.

Observing your own teachers gives you only a bit of the knowledge you need to put a course together, deliver it, and keep a bunch of students happy.

But all universities have a complex mission, and teaching the next generation of scholars is a big part of it.

Comment: _If you are good enough to be hired primarily as a researcher at an R1 university in the US then the hiring decision won't hinge much on your background as a teacher_ — Unless it does. I have seen teaching experience used to break ties between faculty candidates with comparable research records.  (I work at an R1.)

Comment: @JeffE, yes, of course, but it was probably other considerations that got the candidates to that stage. Young tenure track folks at R1 places are hired primarily for their research potential and a hope that they will be adequate or better teachers. At small liberal arts colleges it is pretty much flipped.

Answer (score 2):

This depends by area of study and geography. In the area I did my Ph.D. (pure math), most new job candidates have taught (i.e. been the primary lecturer) for several courses, though the importance of that varies on the type of institution they get their job at. In the applied area I have pivoted to, many applicants have no teaching experience at all; some have been TAs in a course or two. In my wife's area (social sciences), having some teaching experience is frequent enough to differentiate you as a candidate, but not the norm.

Rather than the usual "tell us more about your area and we'll tell you" approach, I'll put it differently.

1. Approach it **empirically**. Look up 5-6 junior faculty in your field whose career path you would like to emulate. Find their CVs online. Did they have teaching experience prior to their 1st postdoc (or other post Ph.D. position)? What else is interesting about their CV?
2. Think about **flexibility**. Regardless of whether you *have* to, wouldn't you like to *try* whether you like teaching and whether you're good at it? In the case you pivot to a nonacademic career (which is increasingly common even for people who think they're going to become academics), wouldn't it be a good experience to have on your resume?

Finally, consider the specifics of options you have. Some "teaching" opportunities for Ph.D.'s are awful; underpaid with lots of busy work and very little independence. Others are super. And there are periods during any Ph.D. program when you need to put your head down and read, or do demanding empirical research, or just write; and there are periods where, let's face it, you are pushing your cognitive limits and need to take breaks anyway, and there's no reason you couldn't fit in teaching (and learn some valuable time management skills at the same time). So **if you have the privilege that teaching is not a necessity but a privilege, be choosy of the specific opportunity and timing when to do it.**

Comment: In my experience on mathematics faculty hiring committees, it's quite common that a CV will not list any teaching duties (or perhaps say something like "Teaching Assistant 2014-2016" that doesn't tell you what duties were involved.  Most applicants provide additional information about their teaching experience in other parts of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Take this from another angle, the comments about this issue by Richard Feynman. Presumably somebody with a foundation-building Nobel in physics should be able to write his own ticket. If he did not want to teach, he could just go sit in his office and think about nearly anything he wanted to.

But he wanted to teach. Indeed, he made a lot of effort to try to teach his students to a high standard.

For him, teaching was something that filled the gaps when his research was not producing huge gratifying results. At least I'm doing my students some good, even if my research is frozen. It helped his attitude and his morale. And that would help him through those dry periods that everybody gets.

So look at teaching as something that can be an enjoyable and rewarding experience.